# Требуется рассылать на сторонние веб серверы тысячи callback's. Как лучше реализовать?

Tags: php, многопоточность, curl, callback

Каждые 5мин по 1-3тыс запросов с POST данными (не тяжёлые).
php curl/curl-multi не хватает.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробней...возможно можно не отправлять эти 1000-3000 запросов а формировать пакет данных и отсылать все вместе?..

Comment: Надо именно раздельными запросами отсылать. Поправить ПО всех клиентов(получателей) для формирования пакетов не получится.
У curl_multi узкое место в кол-ве потоков, разницы между 30 и 800 практически нет. 
Пока в голову приходит только написать демон на С# который будет принимать сразу весь массив запросов и рассылать в уже в 1000 потоков.

Comment: для чего вам понадобилось так часто рассылать пост запросы?.....т.е. в чем суть задачи?...опишите подробей )

Answer (score 1):

используйте - AngryCurl
https://github.com/2naive/AngryCurl

имея на руках список proxy-серверов и идентификаторов браузера (useragent), на лету можно переключаться + следующие плюшки:

- многопоточность
- загрузка proxy-list из файла/массива
- удаление дубликатов прокси-серверов
- проверка работоспособности proxy
- проверка отдаваемого прокси-сервером контента
- загрузка useragent-list из файла/массива
- подмена proxy/useragent «на лету»
- предотвращение установления прямых соединений без использования proxy/useragent, при использовании списков
- работа с callback function
- работа с цепочками запросов
- режим «веб-консоли»
- логирование действий